# Aurelia CLI can't import chart.js TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm using typescript with aurelia/aurelia-cli. I've npm installed `chart.js` and added it to my `aurelia.json` file:

```
"dependencies": [
      ...
      {
        "name": "chartjs",
        "path": "../node_modules/chart.js/dist",
        "main": "Chart"
      },
]
```

I've also ran typings:

```
typings install dt~chart.js --global --save
```

Now I'm trying to import it in one of my components

```
import * as Chart from 'chartjs'
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'chartjs'.
```

I've also tried:

```
... from 'chart'
... from 'Chart'
... from 'Chart.js'
... from 'chartjs'
import * as chart ...
import * as chartjs ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing my import and aurelia.json file.

aurelia.json

```
{
    "name": "chartjs",
    "path": "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min"
},
```

import statement

```
import 'chartjs';
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring an empty module? e.g in a declaration file like `index.d.ts`, add:

```
declare module "chart.js";
```

I find this is a good starting point for importing 3rd party libraries. Further info can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries

If there are no errors and you can use the plain js `chart.js` functions, it means that the library has been included but the types have not.

Also if you are using Typescript 2.0 I think you should be installing the types like this:

```
npm install --save @types/chartjs
```

Comment: If I remove all the content of the index.d.ts file and just add `declare module "chart.js";` then the error goes away. What do you mean that the library has been included and the types have not?

Comment: So if you declare a module like that, all imports from the module will have the any type. You no longer have any type checking but as long as you have correctly loaded the module, you should be able to use the js. If the module has not been loaded and you try to use it, you'll get a bunch of runtime errors. js libraries don't always have type definitions, so this way you can use a plain js library without any typedefs.

Comment: When I declare the module like this the visual studio error went away but when the app tries to compile it throws the error that it can't find 'chart.js' and it crashes the program

Answer (score 0):

I know Chart.js works with Aurelia as we use it in one of our demo apps for workshops. In the demo app it is imported like this: `import Chart from 'chartjs';` but that is ES2015, not TypeScript.

Also, the configuration should look like this in `aurelia.json`:

```
      {
        "name": "chartjs",
        "path": "../node_modules/chart.js/Chart.min",
        "exports": "Chart"
      }
```

Comment: Are you guys using chartjs v1 or v2?

Comment: It looks like I have 2.4.0

Comment: So why is the exports property needed? I thought that was for legacy libraries that use global scripts

Comment: It might not be any more. The config I posted was last updated in August.